# Cannot authenticate anymore with new Google OAuth 2.0 token endpoint (v3)

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-openid

I have a bunch of tests using Google Accounts as Identity Provider with OAuth 2.0 that are failing since 5th of december with an error around the `expires_in` field of the access token response that is no more a `JSON Number` but a `String` (I'm using `grant_type=authorisation_code`, but that shouldn't make any difference):

```
{
   "access_token": "ya29.1gD56tBWtHW3K7oZ0FINTnsqa4VYiE2YGZeQXgJ4ID79E-mZxNWoyYi7pKrs_Vyxj8FZbuxh_RGTJw",
   "token_type": "Bearer",
   "expires_in": "3600",
   "refresh_token": "1/dGjGYC7sDFaBwpdUVpkJP2mYFYTU8HAh7T6szsKGYTs"
}
```

I'm not using any OAuth 2.0 Client library, so I directly deal with the JSON content.

I did noticed that the both the [OpenIDConnect](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect) and OAuth2WebServer developers web pages have been updated the 5th of December.

As there is no history available, I could not see clearly what have been changed, but I noticed that the token endpoint URL (returned by the OpenID Connect Discovery Endpoint) has now a `v3/` path segment.

After some googling, I found the old token endpoint (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token), and it appears that this endpoint returns me an access token response with `expires_in` expressed as a JSON Number.

After reading the OAuth 2.0 specification, it appears to me me that `expires_in` should be expressed as a Number, not a String, and so the new response format is not compliant in regards to the standard.

See RFC 6749, Section 4.1.4 and Appendix #14 for the `expires_in` syntax (only digits).

Are there any plans to fix this on Google side ? Or do we (any OAuth 2.0 client in fact) have to deal with an additional special case (let's call that flexibility :) ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

I've pushed a change that updates this endpoint to return the expires_in field as a JSON Number rather than a String as per the spec from RFC 6749.

Comment: Thanks @mdietz, I can now see the v3 token endpoint returning JSON Number instead of JSON String

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for letting us know. We are looking into this and will try to fix this soon.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the "expires_in" is a recommended field, not a required one; so your implementation should be prepared to deal with omitted or erroneously parsing values.

But of course Google should follow the spec if they intended to provide this functionality. I've contacted Googler's on OpenID Connect working interop list for that, hoping they'll respond accordingly.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer. Also, I'm not sure I agree that just because a field is recommended you should suddenly be prepared to accept non-spec compliant values. Missing, yes, but when present they should still be spec compliant.

Comment: consider it best practice for input parsing; an implementation should not break on it, which is what seems to have happened here judging from the subject; also (although not recommended) JSON objects can have multiple values for the same key, so when this is the case any string values should be ignored and a number value should be parsed out

Comment: Thanks for the comments and advises. I've fixed my side and wanted Googlers to know about this regression. Hopefully, we'll see improvements soon :)